# NGINX open socket left in connection и TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 TIME_WAIT?

Tags: nginx, tcp-ip, php-fpm, fastcgi

Есть web-сервер работает на связке NGINX + PHP-FPM. Перешли на https, приняли решение сделать поддержку http2, пришлось поставить новый NGINX. После "nginx restart" в логах "nginx/error.log" валится:

nginx/error.log

```
2017/07/23 13:48:30 [notice] 3284#3284: signal process started
2017/07/23 13:48:30 [alert] 2892#2892: *33356 open socket #11 left in connection 4
2017/07/23 13:48:30 [alert] 2887#2887: *33398 open socket #44 left in connection 15
2017/07/23 13:48:30 [alert] 2892#2892: *33364 open socket #38 left in connection 23
2017/07/23 13:48:30 [alert] 2884#2884: *33395 open socket #23 left in connection 16
2017/07/23 13:48:30 [alert] 2892#2892: aborting
2017/07/23 13:48:30 [alert] 2887#2887: aborting
2017/07/23 13:48:30 [alert] 2884#2884: aborting
и т.д...
```

netstat -n -t -o | grep timewait выдает:

```
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:9000 127.0.0.1:38936 TIME_WAIT timewait (3.17/0/0)
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:9000 127.0.0.1:40763 TIME_WAIT timewait (48.73/0/0)
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:9000 127.0.0.1:37674 TIME_WAIT timewait (0.00/0/0)
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:9000 127.0.0.1:37464 TIME_WAIT timewait (0.00/0/0)
и таковых очень много...
```

Используемые версии ПО:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
nginx/1.12.1
OpenSSL 1.0.2l
PHP 5.5.9
```

---

### Из файла конфигурации NGINX:

```
worker_processes 8;

events {
    worker_connections 25000;
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
}

http {
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;

client_max_body_size 30m;
client_header_timeout 15;
client_body_timeout 15;
send_timeout 10;
keepalive_timeout 30 15;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
reset_timedout_connection on;

gzip on;
server_tokens off;

upstream backend {
  server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

  server_name sitename.com;

ssl_certificate /path/sitename_com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /path/sitename_com.key;
ssl_session_timeout 1d;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:100m;
ssl_dhparam /path/dhparam.pem;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers '...';
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
ssl_trusted_certificate /path/sitenamecab.pem;
resolver ip-adress; #ip-адрес из "resov.conf"

gzip off;

location ~ \.php$ {
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   fastcgi_pass backend;
   fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
   fastcgi_buffers 8 256k;
   fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
   fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
   fastcgi_param HTTP_SCHEME https;
   include fastcgi.conf;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  ... тут почти тоже самое, что и для listen 443 кроме - нет записей для ssl, gzip on и нет fastcgi_param HTTP_SCHEME https;
 }

}
```

---

### Из файла конфигурации PHP-FPM:

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
listen.backlog = 3000
pm = static
pm.max_children = 2000
pm.max_requests = 3000
```

До установки новой версии NGINX, со старой (nginx/1.4.6) таких ошибок не было. Сервер работает, сайт открывается, но думаю так оставлять нельзя. В сети о таких проблемах есть информация, но как исправить не понятно. Если убрать из "nginx.conf" секцию "server" с "ssl и http2" и оставить только "server" с "listen 80;" ничего не меняется (естестственно, перезапуская после изменения NGINX). Также ничего не меняется, если уменьшить "worker_connections", например с 25000 до 2000, и если уменьшить, например, с 2000 до pm.max_children = 500 и с 3000 до pm.max_requests = 750 (естестственно, перезапуская после измения php-fpm) тоже не решает данной проблемы. Что делать? Куда смотреть?

Comment: попробуйте вместо `pm = static` поставить `pm = ondemand` чтоб чайлд процесс не висел - у меня была схожая ситуация, мемори лики и тд происходили, сделал ондеманд, все ок вроде. я понимаю нагрузки и тд. нужен статик, но ведь памяти у сервера тоже не тонна

Comment: p.s. вместо `127.0.0.1:9000` сделайте `unix:/var/run/php-fpm.backend.sock` если все происходит внутри 1го сервера. и еще - логируйте `crit` ошибки, все подряд нету смысла логировать - зачем тратить лишний io?

Comment: причиной `open socket left` может быть много: 1. нормальное поведение php-fpm-а убивать чайлд после Н кол.во запросов (директива: `pm.max_requests`) чтоб респаунить и как результат nginx теряет хендлер соединения и кричит об этом. 2. мемори лик который происходит от большого количества висячих чайлдов и как результат чайлд "умирает" и тд...  надо дебажить на сервере, мониторить состояние памяти (`htop` в помошь), количество чайлд процессов при режиме `ondemand` чтоб понять реально ли есть большая нагрузка или проблема не в этом?

Comment: Проблема точно не в нагрузке! В том то и дело, что нагрузки сейчас как таковой вообще нет! Сейчас сервер загружен максимум на 5-10% от его обычной нагрузки! Оперативной памяти тоже много (32 Гб), более 50-60% из нее свободно. Как раз пока нет нагрузки, мы и решили обновить ПО, поэкспериментировать и перейти на https.

Comment: С сокетов мы наоборот перешли на tcp, причем тестировали и то и другое, прошло уже при этом несколько лет, т.к. у нас очень часто бывает по несколько тысяч запросов одномоментно, а сокеты насколько я понимаю более быстрые, но не рекомендуется, когда запросов более 1000. По этой же причине стоит и pm = static и завышены почти все лимиты.

Повторю, до установки новой версии NGINX за несколько лет работы, со старой (nginx/1.4.6) таких ошибок не было. Как только поставили новую появилось то, о чем я написал выше.

Comment: а эти логи создают какую либо проблему? т.е. имеется в виду если все ок работает, а это просто алерты, то может есть смысл сделать `error_log: some/path crit`